# Calling multiple dll imports with the same method name

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, unsafe

I'm importing several unmanaged c++ DLL's into my project however the imported DLLs have the same method name which causes compiler issues.  For example;

```
unsafe class Myclass
{
   [DllImport("myfirstdll.dll")]
   public static extern bool ReturnValidate(long* bignum);

   [DllImport("myseconddll.dll")]
   public static extern bool ReturnValidate(long* bignum);

   public Myclass
   {
      int anum = 123;
      long passednum = &anum;
      ReturnValidate(passsednum);
   }
}
```

Now what I'd like to do would be rename the method on import.  Something like;

```
[DllImport("myseconddll.dll")]
public static extern bool ReturnValidate(long bignum) AS bool ReturnValidate2(long bignum);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could provide any name for your imported function, you should only specify in `DllImport` the name of the function in it, using `EntryPoint` property. So you code could look like:

```
[DllImport("myfirstdll.dll", EntryPoint="ReturnValidate")]  
public static extern bool ReturnValidate1(long bignum);  

[DllImport("myseconddll.dll", EntryPoint="ReturnValidate")]  
public static extern bool ReturnValidate2(long bignum);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the EntryPoint property of DllImport attribute.

```
[DllImport("myseconddll.dll", EntryPoint = "ReturnValidate")]
public static extern bool ReturnValidate2(long bignum);
```

Now when you call ReturnValidate2 in your C# code, you will effectively call ReturnValidate on myseconddll.dll.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `EntryPoint` parameter:

```
[DllImport("myfirstdll.dll", EntryPoint="ReturnValidate")]
public static extern bool ReturnValidate1(long bignum);

[DllImport("myseconddll.dll", EntryPoint="ReturnValidate")]
public static extern bool ReturnValidate2(long bignum);
```

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx